# Dynamically creating a connection string for a database just created

Tags: c#

I have created a database programmatically.

Is there any way to create its connection string dynamically using C#, so that after the database creation all data is stored in the new database using C#.

Comment: Welcome at stackoverflow. Please see [ask[ and [mcve] on how to ask good questions. What have you tried thios far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: You must be using some connection string to create database dynamically. You just need to change the database name in that connection string. If you share the existing connection string and the how you create database , appropriate solution can be suggested.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Not necessarily

Comment: The answer to your question is _yes_

Answer (score 1):

I have use this in my C# widows form app and it works for me. Change it according to your needs.

You need to add namespace:

```
//using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;  
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

and add below code:

```
try
    {
         SqlConnectionStringBuilder _connectionString = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
         _connectionString.DataSource = @".\SQLEXPRESS";
         _connectionString.InitialCatalog = "databaseName"; //add database name which created dynamically 
         _connectionString.IntegratedSecurity = true;

    }
catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Not able to create connection string. Error : " +ex);
        }
```

Comment: Smo is not required. SqlConnectionStringBuilder is in the System.Data.SqlClient namespace.

Answer (score 1):

You could also used [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ConnectionStringPT/) which will create ConnectionString for you. 
After installing package

```
Install-Package ConnectionStringPT
```

You will just need to invoke:

```
  var connectionString = ConnectionString.GetSqlServerConnectionString("localhost", "dbName");
```